# Shell script exits unexpectedly, when calling another shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell

I'm creating a java application that calls shell script.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new Processuilder("./script.sh", path1, path2);
Process p = pb.start();
```

this starts the script.sh file.
PROBLEM occurs when script.sh calls another shell script which is @ path2.

```
======script.sh=====
1.#some code 
2.
3.
4.
5.
6. cd $2    # works till here, and changes directory

7. chmod +x script2.sh
8. ./script2.sh
.
.#remaining code
===========
```

the script exits @ line7 without any error or warning.
Please guide.

Comment: also i tried using : 
$2/script2.sh
source ./script2.sh
sh ./script2.sh
but none worked.

Comment: Why are you doing chmod from inside the script? Why not `chmod +x script2.sh` beforehand?

Comment: chmod is done before hand too, 
the command was added for safer side, if script2 is replaced at sometime.

Comment: Ok try commenting out chmod command and see how it behaves?

Comment: chmod +x script2.sh > log.txt ==>> created empty log file.
commenting the command worked.
thanks.. :)

Comment: Glad to know your problem got solved.

Comment: Try `chmod +x script2.sh > log.file` or `2> log.file` and read log. Furthermore check your path. To this effect insert `echo pwd` before `chmod +x script2.sh` line